# Monotonicity of the Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am working through Baby Rudin, and encountered the following remark:

> If $f$ and $g\in\mathcal{L}(\mu)$ on $E$, and if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for $x\in E$, then
>   $$\int_{E}fd\mu\leq \int_E gd\mu.$$

Given a measurable function $f$, $\int_{E}fd\mu$ is always defined, but $f$ only belongs to $\mathcal{L}(\mu)$ when $$\Bigg|\int_{E}fd\mu\Bigg|<\infty.$$
(Edit: as harfe pointed out, it should be $\int_{E}|f|d\mu$ instead).

My question is, does the remark remain true if we only assume $f$ and $g$ to be measurable instead of being in $\mathcal{L}(\mu)$? It seems to be true, because of two cases:

1. If $\int_{E}fd\mu=-\infty$, then there is nothing to show.
2. If $\int_{E}fd\mu=\infty$, then it must follow (?) that $\int_{E}gd\mu=\infty$ as well, so we get $\infty\leq \infty$.

Any help appreciated.

Edit: I just realized that in my situation, I only need $f$ measurable and $g\in \mathcal{L}(\mu)$, but comments at any level of generality are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your definition of $\mathcal L(\mu)$ is not correct in my opinion.
It is usually defined as the set of measurable functions $f$ such that
$$
\int_E |f|\,\mathrm d\mu<\infty.
$$

Your argument for the cases
$\int_E f\,\mathrm d\mu=-\infty$
and
$\int_E f\,\mathrm d\mu=\infty$
is correct.
However, there is another possibility if $f$ is not in $\mathcal L(\mu)$.
It can happen that the integral is not defined or does not exist.
This is the case if
$$
\int_E f^+\,\mathrm d\mu=\infty
\quad\text{and}\quad
\int_E f^-\,\mathrm d\mu=\infty,
$$
where $f^+,f^-$ are the positive and negative part of $f$
(using the Notation as in Baby Rudin).

This is the reason why the author adds the conditions $f,g\in\mathcal L(\mu)$.